# Access Google API Contacts without login in gmail

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, access-token, google-oauth

I want to access Google Contacts API in java. So basically I am confused whether it is possible or not, I want to access user information without login into gmail with client id and client secret. please provide me some link or idea to achieve this. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.

[Authorizing requests to the Google Contacts API service](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#authorizing_requests_to_the_api_name_service)

Wish these two samples helps you.

- [OAuth 2.0 and the Google OAuth Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/oauth2#overview)
- [Google Contact example](https://github.com/google/gdata-java-client/blob/master/java/sample/contacts/ContactsExample.java)